# Is there a way to not old urls back to the homepage utilizing the admin panel?

Tags: url, url-rewrite, product-urls

Or do you have to use the htaccess.

The reason i ask is because i just changed our URL structure from www to http and for legacy URL's that might be out there existing on other websites, i do not want them to end up on the homepage.. rather i'd like them to just end up on the old page.. even if it's not the right page any longer.

I've looked through the panel configurations and i believe i set it up originally to send all 404's or old pages to the homepage. I understand i could use catalog > URL redirects but i don't want to possibly have to go through a hundred URL's.. That would be a tedious way of doing that.

Thanks in advance.

update to be a bit more clear:

That sounds good but i just want you to be clear on what the problem is.. here's a better senario... we send out and email that has a link like so:  `http://www.goodstuff.com/buy/whateverproduct`  <   when i change the base and secure url to `http://goodstuff.com/buy/whateverproduct` < the link above with www no longer works and directs to the home page. I would like to still preserve that link as well. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with 2 lines in the htaccess file rewriting URLs with *www* to non-*www*

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: i updated my question just to be more clear. Thanks for lending a hand already.

Comment: what I provided will redirect the url + whatever comes after it to a url with the www. Isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: The main reason i made the switch is for google advertising.. they prefer http:// without the www. But for all other pages that might be out there that link to our website like so:  http://www.goodstuff.com/whatever  < these no longer work and just redirect to goodstuff.com

Comment: so did you try what I suggested?

Comment: I'm going to try right now. Thank you, i'll let you know in a few minutes. Also, i really enjoy the idea of magestackday.com I saw it in your profile. cool stuff.  =]

Comment: Sorry for such the delay, it doesn't work. Whenever i click on an old URL that has the www in it like so > 'http://www.mywebsite.com/this/product.html'... it automatically redirects me to the homepage...

Comment: Did you change the base url in the backend? Is the mage_run_code still correct?

Comment: I changed the base URL's to http instead of www... What is the mage_run_code function?

Comment: I need your guys help still.

Comment: Redirect loop when both the backend secure and unsecure URLS have been changed and the rewrite conditions are added to htaccess. Website is down. I don't think you guys understand the question. =/